# Lookup a value in pandas table and if not there then interpolate between values in python

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, lookup

I have a pandas table of wind speed values ("WS") and I want to look up the corresponding power values in a lookup table ("PC").  If the exact value doesn't exist, then I want it to interpolate between the values in the lookup table. Is this simple and possible to do? I was able to accomplish this in excel so I feel like there should be a way to do this here in python.

Data in text:

```
print (WS)
0    6.869516
1    6.366496
2    5.863476
3    5.360457
4    5.073017
5    4.569997
6    3.995117
7    3.563957
8    3.204657
9    3.132797
dtype: float64
```

---

```
print (PC)
      WS  Power [kWh]
0   0.0            0
1   0.5            0
2   1.0            0
3   1.5            0
4   2.0            0
5   2.5            0
6   3.0            0
7   3.5           55
8   4.0          128
9   4.5          211
10  5.0          310
11  5.5          431
12  6.0          567
13  6.5          727
14  7.0          910
15  7.5         1119
16  8.0         1356
```

What is the best way and simplest way to accomplish this? For example, for WS[0] which is 6.869516, this value falls between 6.5 and 7 WS in the look up table this would give a power value between 727 and 910 kwh but probably closer to the 910 value. I would want the code to interpolate between the values and split out the interpolated power value for each WS in the "WS" pandas table.

Comment: It would be great if you could include [`re-producible dataset`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4985099) with input & expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.interp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) because values of `PC['WS']` are increasing:

```
df = WS.to_frame('WS')
df['new'] = np.interp(WS, PC['WS'], PC['Power [kWh]'])
print (df)
         WS         new
0  6.869516  862.242856
1  6.366496  684.278720
2  5.863476  529.865472
3  5.360457  397.230594
4  5.073017  327.670114
5  4.569997  224.859406
6  3.995117  127.287082
7  3.563957   64.337722
8  3.204657   22.512270
9  3.132797   14.607670
```